# Powershell design issue - too many if(deviceId)

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a Powershell script, and it reads in files for each device version, and some of the files are different format, so I have to post-process the files to get the correct format, or handle it differently due to different data.  So I have about 2 groups of 12 if statements (for 12 devices) to handle the differences.  If it was object oriented, I would have classes to handle these, but I couldn't get the object oriented PowerShell working.  Does anyone have any ideas how to handle this sort of thing?  My list of devices has grown from 3 to about 20 (I have about 8 left), and I hadn't foreseen this at the start that more would be given to Parse, causing spaghetti code.

My code looks like this:

```
     if($currentVersion -Match '^(68)') 
     {
          #special code for 68
          #prepare Map for ErrorCodeList and Error Descriptions before loop through each error
          $errorCodeListFile = Join-Path -Path $pathViewBase -ChildPath 
          $errorCodeListBase68
      

          #call method to return basePathFull cppFile method contents
          $matchFound = Get-MethodContents -codePath $File[0] -methodNameToReturn "Device68::GetFromCode" -followingMethodName "Device4=68::SkipIt" 
          #call method to get case info
          $resultsCase = (Get-CaseContents68 -parsedCaseMethod $matchFound )  
      }
      if($currentVersion -Match '^(30)')
      {
          $HopResultMap = [ordered]@{}
          $HopResultMap2 = [ordered]@{}
          #prepare Map for ErrorCodeList and Error Descriptions before loop through each error
          $errorCodeListFile = Join-Path -Path $pathViewBase -ChildPath $errorCodeListBase30  
          #call method to return basePathFull cppFile method contents
          $matchFound = Get-MethodContents -codePath $File[0] -methodNameToReturn "30Device::GetFromCode" -followingMethodName "30Device::GetFirst" #
          #call method to get case info
          $HopResultMap = (Get-Contents30 -fileContent $matchFound)  
          $FileHandler = Join-Path -Path $basePathFull -ChildPath "30Device\30Device.h"
          $matchFound2 = Get-MethodContents -codePath $FileHandler -methodNameToReturn "NoError" -followingMethodName "PageID;"
          $HopResultMap2 = Get-Contents30_b -fileContent $matchFound2 
          #combine the data structures so can reuse 70 process flow/variables


          $resultsCase = foreach ($kvp in $HopResultMap.GetEnumerator()){ #foreach key in $HopResultMap[1]
          Write-Host $kvp.sdkDesc
          Write-Host $kvp.sdkOutErr
          Write-Host $HopResultMap2[$kvp.sdkErrKey]
          [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
                sdkErr      = $HopResultMap2[$kvp.sdkErrKey]
                sdkDesc     = $kvp.sdkDesc
                sdkOutErr   = $kvp.sdkOutErr
          }
          }#resultsCase
       }
       #etc
       #plus another section like this later for special processing needed later for different data pieces
```

It's not all different code for the different device versions.  There is about 1000+ lines shared, plus shared functions, and also separate functions for each version to handle reading different files/layouts.

I am using PowerShell 5.1 and VSCode.

Comment: So you're just looking for a better way to handle this? What format are the versions? Can you not cast type of `[version]`  to it?

Comment: One suggestion might be to replace the if statements with `switch -regex ($currentVersion) { ... }` but still I'm not sure this answers your question.  Can you clarify what your ultimate goal is please?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - it's not a cast type of thing.  For each device version, it has completely sections of about 30 lines of different code to handle the data read from different file types.  Or different queries.

Comment: @Daniel - I do have some switch statements in the beginning of the code so I can run it for the different devices instead of all of them.  But the data processing is different and each device has a minimum of 30 lines of code for data processing. One file read has a different data structure, and has to put data together with another data structure/file read to get the same data format to handle the data the same as other versions later. I can't consolidate all code together for each device version because different things happen at different times, to prevent extra file reads or DB queries.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing it okay.  Without actually seeing the data processing code for each of the different versions it's hard to tell what you can refactor to simplify the approach.  If each version requires different processing then what other option could you have?

Comment: @Daniel - my only idea was getting the class thing working, but from what I read, its not recommended/easy.

Comment: Can you show us some of these files to parse the version from?

Comment: For your classes idea, how are you expecting that that would work differently?  Would that remove all the different processing scenarios?

Comment: @Michele instead of full-on classes, maybe you should be constructing custom ps objects? Or break shared code into separate functions for re-use?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale - I do have several PSCustomObjects.  I'm just trying to figure out how to take out the complexity of all the if statements, handling the different data inputs.  Like I do 2-3 file reads thru functions, then put it together in a PSCustomObject to use later, but it's all orchestrated for each device in a if block

Comment: As @Theo suggest: if you want to make your script more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), you should focus on the redundant lines in your code *between* the `if`s. If you need any help with that, you need to share some of *that* code. Effentually, you could even make a lookup table that lists all the functions you want to call for a spefic condition.

Comment: @Theo - I added examples of what's in the 30 and what I do to handle the data differently in the 68. The other ones have similar differences, some repeating.

Answer (score 0):

Even the question is very abstract due to the fact that there are no details about what is actually being invoked inside the `if` statements, let me try to answer this with an abstract answer as I believe that the solution for this general (and not just PowerShell) programming issue lays in a

### [**decision table**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_table)

(as defined later in the Wiki: [program embedded decision tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_table#Program_embedded_decision_tables)).

For this -in PowerShell-, you might use a `csv` file ([`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv)) or (embedded) `csv` format ([`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/ConvertFrom-csv)), an [Excel module](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/), a database or a custom functions as [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) for better readability:

```
$DecisionTable = ConvertFrom-SourceTable '
Version Do1 Do2 Do3
------- --- --- ---
^(30)   X       X
^(68)   X
^(70)       X   X'
```

Or even share and scrape your decision table from the internet/intranet with a custom function as [`Read-HtmlTable`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Read-HtmlTable):

```
$WikiTable = Read-HtmlTable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_table -Table 2
```

With that, you might consider to use the native [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) cmdlet, something like:

```
$WikiTable.Where{
    $currentVersion -Match $_.Input 
}.ForEach{
    Invoke-Expression $_.'Function Pointer'
}
```

But taken the warning:

> [Caution](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression#description)
>
> Take reasonable precautions when using the Invoke-Expression cmdlet in scripts. When using Invoke-Expression to run a command that the user enters, verify that the command is safe to run before running it. In general, it is best to design your script with predefined input options, rather than allowing freeform input.

I would recommend against this and try to **translate your functions into parameter** which you handle in a general function with hardcoded invoke conditions, like:

```
function Do1 { Write-Host 'Do 1' }
function Do2 { Write-Host 'Do 2' }
function Do3 { Write-Host 'Do 3' }

$DecisionTable.Where{
    $currentVersion -Match $_.Version 
}.ForEach{
    if ($_.Do1) { Do1 }
    if ($_.Do2) { Do2 }
    if ($_.Do3) { Do3 }
}
```

Comment: I updated the examples of special code for different typical data handling I need to do for each version.